# Ubuntu on micro sd: file system frequently corrupted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, filesystem, sd-card

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Micro Sd on my surface pro 3. To install it I used a Usb stick created with Unetbootin. I have a dual boot with Windows 10.
There two things I do not understand:
1. In the Ubuntu bar, I have the option "Install release". Why? Isn't it already installed? I mean, I use it every day and I installed software on Ubuntu with no problem
2. Every two/three time I turn on my Surface the grub doesn't work with my keyboard and because of that I am forced to boot in Ubuntu. I think the problem is caused by a corruption of the file system since actually I cannot boot in Ubuntu but I have to run fsck on the partition of the micro sd where Ubuntu is installed. After that I reboot and everything works correctly. So, are there any issues in installing Ubuntu on a micro sd? I did something wrong or is it just a problem of my surface / micro sd / bug in Ubuntu?

Comment: There could be a problem, that the buffers (in RAM) are not written to the card before the system shuts down. It can be caused by unplugging the card before completely shutting down. But I have seen the same thing happen with SSD drives connected via USB. In that case it was fixed by connecting the external box for the SSD to an external power supply, that was turned on until I was sure that the system was completely shut down. Would it be possible for you to supply power for the card reader externally (directly from the power grid, not only via the computer)?

Comment: No because I need to use the computer in mobility. The card reader is integrated in the pc. So, you speak about ram... My surface has only 4 gigabytes of ram and I created a small swap partition (about 500/800mb). Could it be a problem?

Comment: I think the amount of RAM is sufficient. It is possible, but very unlikely, that the RAM is bad (could be tested with memtest). You can check, how much RAM and swap, that is used. If you avoid keeping too many tabs open in your browser, and avoid keeping too many programs running at the same time, I think there will be enough RAM, and there will be only a small amount of swapping. - It might help to open a terminal window and run the command `sync` just before shutdown or reboot. `sync` flushes the buffers (writes them to the card). That reduces the risk of a corrupted file system.